# JSON object is undefined in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

In my Django project I'm trying to create a page that constantly displays the current state of a certain field in a database. I'm using ajax to do that but for reason the response object I'm returning keeps coming back as undefined.

Here is my view:

```
def call_ajax(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        userp = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        accepted = userp.recent_call.accepted
        hello = "hello"

        ajax_vars = {
            'accepted':accepted,
            'hello':hello,
        }

        return JsonResponse(ajax_vars)
```

Here is the relevant javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(response){
    ajax_call(response);
});

function ajax_call(response){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/calls/call_ajax/',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: {
            accepted: response.accepted,
            hello: response.hello,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.hello)
           $('#info').html('<p>'+response.hello+'</p>');
           },
        error: function() {
            $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
           }
    });
    setInterval(function() { ajax_call(response); },10000)
}
```

For some reason the console is logging that the response object is undefined. Any tips?

Comment: `response` should be an argument for `success` handler ... Currently it's an argument of `ready`, but you're not passing it. Notice, that values for arguments are given, when invoking a function, not at definition.